# bs4 python not finding text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have an html document that I grabbed via beautiful soup.  An extract of the html is at the bottom of this question.  I'm using beautiful soup and selenium.

I have been told that I'm only allowed to extract so much data per hour, and when I get this page to wait a while (a good hour).

This is how I'm trying to extract the data:

```
def get_page_data(self):
    opts = Options()
    opts.headless = True
    assert opts.headless  # Operating in headless mode
    browser_detail = Firefox(options=opts)
    url = self.base_url.format(str(self.tracking_id))
    print(url)
    browser_detail.get(url)
    self.page_data = bs4(browser_detail.page_source, 'html.parser')
    Error_Check = 1 if len(self.page_data.findAll(text='Error Report Number')) > 0 else 0
    Error_Check = 2 if len(self.page_data.findAll(text='exceeded the maximum number of sessions per hour allowed')) > 0 else Error_Check
    print(self.page_data.findAll(text='waiting an hour and trying your query again')). ##<<--- The Problem is this line.
    print(self.page_data)
    return Error_Check
```

THe problem is this line:

```
print(self.page_data.findAll(text='waiting an hour and trying your query again')). ##<<--- The Problem is this line.
```

The code can't find the line in the page.  What am I missing?  Thanks

```
<html><head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
<link href="/CMPL/styles/ogm_style.css;jsessionid=rw9pc8-bncrIy_4KSZmJ8BxN2Z2hnKVwcr79Vho4-99gxTPrxNbo!-68716939" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<body>
<!-- Content Area -->
<table style="width:100%; margin:auto;">
<tbody><tr valign="top">
<td class="ContentArea" style="width:100%;">
<span id="messageArea">
<!-- /tiles/messages.jsp BEGIN -->
<ul>
</ul><b>
</b><table style="width:100%; margin:auto; white-space: pre-wrap; text-align: left;">
<tbody><tr><td align="left"><b><li><font color="red"></font></li></b></td>
<td align="left"><font color="red">You have exceeded the maximum number of sessions per hour allowed for the public queries. You may still access the public</font></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><font color="red"><li style="list-style: none;"></li></font></td>
<td align="left"><font color="red">queries by waiting an hour and trying your query again. The RRC public queries are provided to facilitate online research and are not intended to be accessed by automated tools or scripts. For questions or concerns please contact the RRC HelpDesk at helpdesk@rrc.state.tx.us or 512-463-7229</font></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
<p>....more html...</p>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but if your are:

```
html = [your code above]
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
soup = bs4(html, 'lxml')
data = soup.find_all('font', color="red")
data[3].text
```

Output:

```
'queries by waiting an hour and trying your query again. The RRC public queries are provided to facilitate online research and are not intended to be accessed by automated tools or scripts. For questions or concerns please contact the RRC HelpDesk at helpdesk@rrc.state.tx.us or 512-463-7229'
```

Comment: Hi Jack,  I'll take it.  this one appears to work fo rme. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following css selector

```
tr:last-child:not([valign])
```

i.e.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
html = '''yourHTML'''    
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')   
item = soup.select_one('tr:last-child:not([valign])')
print(item.text)
```

If this returns more than one item you could loop the list filtering for items containing the string of interest. You could restrict to just a selector of `td` and do something similar.

```
items = soup.select('tr:last-child:not([valign])')
for item in items:
    if 'queries by waiting an hour' in item.text:
        print(item.text)
```

BeautifulSoup 4.7.1

Comment: THank you QHarr, I'm sorry, Jack came first and it worked.  +1 tho.  Nice idea.

Comment: No worries and appreciate you taking the time to feedback and vote :-)